# Create Excel array based on search function

Tags: vb.net, excel

I've got a list in Excel which shows the titles in column A and values in column B, like this:

```
ARTICLE_POSNO       1
ARTICLE_ARTNO       111123  
ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION black pens
ARTICLE_POSNO       2
ARTICLE_ARTNO       280708  
ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION yellow paper
ARTICLE_POSNO       3
ARTICLE_ARTNO       999912      
ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION blue scissors
```

What I'm trying to do is to build a VB function that creates an array that holds the values, so I can then print it something like this:

```
POS ART NO  DESCRIPTION
1   111123  black pens
2   280708  yellow paper
3   999912  blue scissors
```

Below is my current script which searches for the titles -> gets the values next to them and finally send a Msgbox of the value. For this list, that would mean 9 Msgboxes.
Ideally, it would show just one messagebox with all article information on it.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub FindArticles()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MySearch As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim I As Long

    MySearch = Array("ARTICLE_POSNO", "ARTICLE_ARTNO", "ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION")

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000")
        For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    ArtValue = Rng.Offset(0, 1) 'Gather the value to the right
                    MsgBox ArtValue 
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input worksheet is named `Input` and it has the attributes in sequence as in your example, being first column the names and second the values.
 1. Create a new worksheet in your workbook and fill the first row with the names (`POS`, `ART NO`...).
 2. Put this formula in `A2`.

```
=INDEX(Input!$B$1:$B$9,(ROW()-1)*3-3+COLUMN(),1)
```

3. Copy this cell and paste in the final array.

Not much to explain: it takes 1st, 2nd and 3rd of every 3 values in the values column using row position. Modify the length of input array from 9 to your needs. If your the sequence of the input is not constant it can also be accomplished but it's a little longer.

Comment: Thanks, however I would prefer having it in a macro instead as there are lots of other rows with additional information too and I'm going to output some of them using Outlook.Application.